# Python's XlsxWriter Module Inserting Images Sideways

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm adding images from a folder to an excel file using Python's XlsxWriter module, but the images added are all rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the default perhaps being to have the largest dimension become the width, or if there's some other issue. But I can't find anything in the documentation about how to rotate an image.
Below is the code I'm using to create the xlsx document. I don't believe I've inadvertently caused the images to rotate, but I also can't find a way to rotate them back to the correct direction.

```
import xlsxwriter

i=1
j=2
rowNum=1


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('images.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 22)
worksheet.set_row(0, 48)

while i <= 47:
    filename = "ATT" + str(i) + "_Photo 1.jpg"
    cell = "A"+str(j)

    worksheet.set_row(rowNum, 90)
    rowNum+=1

    worksheet.insert_image(cell, filename, {'x_scale':0.25, 'y_scale':0.25})
    i += 1
    j += 1

workbook.close()
```

[image]

Comment: XlsxWriter copies images directly into the target xlsx file. It doesn’t rotate or manipulate them in any way. What happens if you insert one of the images that gets rotated directly into Excel

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The images are, as far as I can tell, added as they are stored in the folder. I don't know why they're showing up sideways.

Comment: My guess would be that the images are showing up sideways because they are in fact sideways. You can verify that by inserting one manually in Excel and seeing what happens. Alternatively, post one to imagur or somewhere accessible on the web.